# When I am using bullet points where do I put the "or"?

Tags: orthography, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions, lists

I have a bullet list. Should I use the word "or" within the bullet points? If so, where should it go? Or do I not use the word "or" for the last bullet point?

Comment: There is normally an introduction before a bulleted list; this can usually be worded to avoid the need for _and_'s, _or_'s etc.

Answer (score 5):

Rephrase the introduction to the list so you don't need a conjunction.

> The user can choose from one of the following options:

Answer (score 5):

If rephrasing gets awkward, you can bullet a complete sentence showing

- this item here with an ending semi-colon;
- this item, which ends in the same semi-colon followed by an "or"; or
- this item, which completes the sentence with a period.

These are [guidelines](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2012/01/punctuating-bullet-points-.html), not steadfast rules that everyone agrees upon.